# Correct way of selecting all rows (including null), except the ones containing string

Tags: mysql, sql

```
SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE comment NOT LIKE '%substring%'
```

comment is VARCHAR

This query doesn't seem to select rows where comment is NULL. Which is strange, cause in my head, NULL is not like '%substring%'

What is the correct way of selecting ALL rows (including nulls) that doesn't have a specific string in them?

Answer (score 3):

`NULL` fails pretty much all comparisons.  Technically, most comparisons are not `false`, but the results is `NULL` -- and `WHERE` filters out any non-true rows.

Include the comparison explicitly:

```
WHERE (comment NOT LIKE '%substring%' OR comment IS NULL)
```

You can consider other alternatives such as defaulting the comment to an empty string (`''`) and defining the column as `NOT NULL`.  Then your original code would work.

Answer (score 3):

> in my head, NULL is not like '%substring%'

Rather than thinking about `NULL` as meaning a value is empty, the better way to understand it is `NULL` means you *don't yet know* what the value is. In other words, you don't yet know whether or not the `NULL` value is or isn't like your string. Because you don't know, the database will err on the side of not producing a false result for the comparison. To fix it, you can do a couple things:

```
WHERE (comment IS NULL OR comment NOT LIKE '%substring%')
```

or

```
WHERE coalesce(comment,'') NOT LIKE '%substring%'
```